# grid not working as expected in Python using Tkinter

Tags: python, grid, tkinter

I am going through a book which says I must use the following code to create a GUI with a label on the top left (co-ordinate (0,0)). In the book, the author prints a screenshot of the GUI and the label it is at (0,0) as expected. But when I run it it is in the center not matter how I change the row,column, columnspan and sticky parameters.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this?

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.inst_lbl = Label(self, text = "Enter password")
        self.inst_lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

root = Tk()

root.title("Password")

root.geometry("250x150")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I get it at the top-left. just cut and pasted. Ubuntu 10 10, python 2.6.5

Comment: Ditto. Ran it on Mac Python 2.6, Ubuntu 2.6/3.1, and Windows 2.7. Top-left in all.

Comment: @joaquin , @samplebias, really? Well I don't know why I am not seeing that. Im on Python 2.2.3 because the book that I am using uses that. Maybe I should upgrade to a newer version to fix this?

Comment: yip upgrading to 2.6 did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: I didnt know python 2.2 was still around...last released in 2003...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are using a very old version of python and Tkinter. If you upgrade, the code you posted will work fine.